# Flask - Getting values

Tags: python, flask

I want to get the "name" and "size" values from what the user typed into a search box.

But the obvious problems are that I'm trying to *get* values from a `method: "POST"` hmtl form.
And my html action just references the `{{ url_for('main') }}` html not where want to retrieve these values in the {{ url_for('search') }} html.

Here are the templates:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, redirect, request


app = Flask(__name__)
conn = sqlite3.connect('shoes.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('main.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        size = request.form.get('size')
        return redirect(url_for('search'))


@app.route("/search/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():

    # Need to get the 'name' and 'search' values from input, so this way is incorrect.
    name = request.args.get("name") 
    size = request.args.get("size")     

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name LIKE ? AND sizes LIKE ? ORDER BY price",
                    ('%'+name+'%','%'+size+'%'))

    p = c.fetchall()

    url = [p[i][0] for i in range(len(p))]
    names = [p[i][1] for i in range(len(p))]
    prices = [p[i][2] for i in range(len(p))]
    sizes = [p[i][3] for i in range(len(p))]
    shoe_type = [p[i][4] for i in range(len(p))]

    return render_template('search.html' , url=url, names=names, prices=prices,
                           sizes=sizes, shoe_type=shoe_type)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

main.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action = "{{ url_for('main') }}" class="form" method = "POST" >

        <h1>Soccer Shoes Finder</h1>
        <div class="line-separator"></div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <input name = "name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input name = "size" type="text" placeholder="Size"/>
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            </div>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

search.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}


    <div class= "container">
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Prices</th>
        <th>Sizes</th>
        <th>Shoe Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for i in range(url|length) %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href={{url[i]}}>aa</td>
        <td>{{names[i]}}</td>
        <td>${{prices[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{sizes[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{shoe_type[i]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Anyone know how could I achieve this? Hopefully what I said makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your main route, seems there is no reason to POST the data here:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

`POST` the data instead directly to your **search** endpoint by changing this line within your **main.html** Jinja template:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" class="form" method="POST">
```

Since this page rendering is dependent on having form data I'd just set it to only accept POST methods, but this is up to you. You need to access the values here using [**request.form**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.form) *(or [request.values](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.values) if you also want to support query string `GET` method)*.

```
@app.route("/search/", methods=["POST"])
def search():
    name = request.form.get("name") 
    size = request.form.get("size")
```

Assuming your database code works the rest of this should work as expected

Comment: Thanks. this works. Probably a dumb question but If I deleted the `redirect` in my main.html how does it know where to redirect when clicking the search button?

Comment: the form `action` attribute tells the **main.html** page to submit the form directly to your **/search/** function

Comment: I see, makes sense.